# On page load - prevent randomly positioned divs from overlapping on top of each other

Tags: jquery, random

I have some code working to randomly place DIVs on screen on page load. See fiddle below. What I am struggling with is how to make them not overlap each other... If this possible?

[jsFiddle link example](http://jsfiddle.net/sfemt7jw/)

Code example inline as below:

```
<style>
body, html {
background: #fff;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding:0; margin:0;
overflow: hidden;
}
div { 
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}   
.decs img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec1f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec2f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec3f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec4f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec1f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec2f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec3f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec4f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec1f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec2f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec3f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec4f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec1f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec2f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec3f.png"></div>
<div class="decs"><img src="images/dec4f.png"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(".decs").each(function(i) {

var e = $(this);

var posx = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)));
var posy = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)));
var widthval = Math.max(0, Math.min(15, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)));

e.css({'left':posx+'%','top':posy+'%','width':widthval+'%'});

});

</script>   
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question you have marked! My question is about checking for overlaps on random position on page load - the one you have marked it as a duplicate of is not the same.

Comment: Also the solution given as an answer to the referred question is not suitable for my requirement - it crashses the browser!